# Easiest way to compare some date stored as LONG (BIGINT) to YEAR in SQL (Derby DB)

Tags: sql, database, derby

I'm looking for easy way how to compare some date in SQL, saved as `long` (BIGINT) value in database (Derby DB) to YEAR `(2015-01-01 <= longValue <= 2015-12-31)`. Is it possible to do it using only SQL methods?

Comment: The answer is yes, but the details depend on your rdbms. Edit your question to include a tag with your rdbms

Answer (score 1):

From Derby documentation it seems it support [Year](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefyearfunc.html) function.

`YEAR('2015-01-01') <= longValue And longValue <= YEAR('2015-12-31')`.

Sorry for missing the error, but I was using my cellphone so it's not always easy. Anyway the problem was that the [date](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj18730.html) shold have been enclosed inside apostrophs, and also your first date was invalid.

Comment: Seems here is the problem: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: The 'EXTRACT YEAR' function is not allowed on the 'INTEGER' type.`. It works if date is saved in DB as `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE`.. I think I must convert (add `TIMESTAMP` type column in DB and transfer data) and then do SQL comparison I think.

Comment: Not working also: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and 'TIMESTAMP' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')`. Maybe the `2015-01-01` should be casted as Date.

Comment: DerbyDb and java are not my specialty. I'm a c# and sql server myself,  but it seems to be consistant with the documentation. Can you update your question to show the sql that generates this error?